# Check if Condition was true fro every iteration Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am running jQuery each.. I need to check if every time the condition was true in the loop then it is True Else if it was False even once it is False.

```
jQuery(".class span").each(function(){
   var attr_Val = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
   if(parseInt(product_obj.length) == attr_Val)
   {
        // if it was true every time, then set its True. Else False    
   }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to know if the condition is true for all elements matched by the selector? If so `each` is not the right thing to use... you probably want a `reduce`

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBool = true;
jQuery(".class span").each(function(){
  var attr_Val = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
  if(parseInt(product_obj.length) != attr_Val)
  {
      myBool = false;   
  }
});
```

I changed your == to !=, to catch everytime it's false, since I dont have to do anything if the result is true.

Basic explanation: I set myBool variable to true, then I run the .each() function. If any of the results dont match, myBool becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

This is that you want.

```
var isFound= true;
jQuery(".class span").each(function(){
   if(parseInt(product_obj.length) != parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"))
   {           
        isFound = false; 
        //it works as break; in each loop
        //for better performance do break loop 
        return false;
   }      
});
```

Comment: is it? This certainly wont return true/false from the call to `each`

Comment: I got the same understading for the question. Maybe OP asked in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarification, what I suspect you're trying to do is one of two things

1. Find all elements which match the selector `.class span` which have a `data-value` attribute matching a predefined value (`product_obj.length`).
2. Determine if all elements which match the selector `.class span` all match a predefined value (`product_obj.length`).

Both/either are easy enough, but neither require the use of jQuery `each`.

For 1. Use filter:

```
var $matched = jQuery(".class span").filter(function(){
   var attr_Val = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
   return parseInt(product_obj.length) == attr_Val;
});
```

for 2. Use filter and length:

```
var $elems = jQuery(".class span");

var $matched = $elems.filter(function(){
   var attr_Val = parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"));
   return parseInt(product_obj.length) == attr_Val;
});
var allMatch = $elems.length === $matched.length;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(".class span").each(function(){
   if(parseInt(product_obj.length) != parseInt($(this).attr("data-value"))
   {
       //if you enter here just ONE time it will return false
        return false;
   }
});
```

hope it helps